# Execute shell & python scripts from commands sent via POP

Tags: python, parsing, raspberry-pi, pop3, raspbian

I have my pi set up to text my phone (XXXXXXXX@vtext.com) through a google account when the CPU reaches or exceeds 45 degrees Celsius. I would like to be able to message back to the account and have the pi execute various scripts based on the content of the message. For instance, I may type "Put the fan on high." and it will execute a script that raises the fan speed. Or if the fan is already on high, I would like to be able to type "Shutdown." and have the pi shutdown. I have the pi checking the account via POP, the only problem is it shuts down every time no matter what I type, I can't figure this one out. This is way beyond my python knowledge.

I must have also screwed with something else at some point because it doesn't run now, this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readTest.py", line 14, in <module>
    rebootMessage = [parser.Parser().parsestr(Reboot) for Reboot in messages]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/parser.py", line 82, in parsestr
    return self.parse(StringIO(text), headersonly=headersonly)
TypeError: expected read buffer, tuple found
```

This is the code:

```
import poplib
import os
from email import parser

pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_conn.user('XXXXXXXXXX')
pop_conn.pass_('XXXXXXXXXX')
#Get messages from server:
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
# Concat message pieces:
rebootMessage = ["\n".join(Reboot[1]) for Reboot in messages]
fanMessage = ["\n".join(PutFanOnHigh[1]) for PutFanOnHigh in messages]
#Parse message intom an email object:
rebootMessage = [parser.Parser().parsestr(Reboot) for Reboot in messages]
fanMessage = [parser.Parser().parsestr(PutFanOnHigh) for PutFanOnHigh in messages]

#If parsestr returns True for the current element (i.e. it's the string you're looking for)
for rebootMessage in messages:
  #os.system('sudo /storage/SKYNET/remoteReboot.sh')
        print rebootMessage
        print fanMessage
#If parsestr returns True for the current element (i.e. it's the string you're looking for)
for fanMessage in messages:
  #os.system('sudo /storage/SKYNET/fanSpeedHigh.py')
        print rebootMessage
        print fanMessage
pop_conn.quit()
```

Comment: Your loop `for rebootMessage in messages:` and `for fanMessage in messages:` both loop over the same elements, neither uses the variable  it's looping over, and neither has anything to do with `rebootMessage`  or `fanMessage` as they're calculated earlier.

Comment: @David Robinson This was originally a script for finding one word, however I didn't want to have 20 files running in my crontabs. I tried to adapt it using what I saw on the code online but I am over my head. I am learning python on codecademy but not fast enough. I'm not quite sure what you are saying to do.

Comment: What are the contents of `fanMessage` and `rebootMessage `? Can you print them and tell us what they are printing?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Updated code above.